How to return null if id does not exist
For the example table acts below:



id
request_id




1
234


2
531



and the query below:
select request_id, id
from acts
where id in (234,531,876)

I need to get the following result:



request_id
id




234
1


531
2


876
null



As you could see there is not row where request_id 876 exists. For these cases null should be returned.
How could I achieve this?

These are arbitrary numbers. You could of course write such query but tomorrow it might be that you nee 235,532, and 877 instead of 234, 531, and 875. What is driving this query? Are these really precisely 3 constants values for ID's that you want to hard code in your query?

Do those request_ids exist in another table, such as request?

Did you mean ... where request_id in (234, 5331, 876)?

Assuming you actually meant to join on request_id not id.
create table acts (id integer, request_id integer);

insert into acts values (1, 234), (2, 531);

select 
   * 
from 
   (values(234), (531), (876)) as t(r_id)  
left join 
    acts on t.r_id  = acts.request_id;

r_id |  id  | request_id 
------+------+------------
  234 |    1 |        234
  531 |    2 |        531
  876 | NULL |       NULL
 

The above creates a VALUES list that you can then LEFT JOIN to acts. In that case the request_id missing in acts will show up with NULL values for the corresponding field in acts.

Conditional logic can be helpful in this situation.
for (Object item : database) {
        if (item.getId() == id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;

